# parameterized SQL script

Tags: sql, parameterized

```
SET ECHO ON
SET VERIFY ON

ACCEPT CNUMBER CHAR PROMPT 'CUSTOMER NUMBER == '
ACCEPT PNUMBER CHAR PROMPT 'PART NUMBER == '
ACCEPT OD date format 'YYYYMMDD' PROMPT 'ORDER DATE == '


DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE CNUM = &CNUMBER AND PNUM = &PNUMBER AND ORDERDATE = to_date(&OD,'YYYYMMDD'); 

PROMPT Done.

--DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE CNUM = 'C111' AND PNUM = 'M001' AND ORDERDATE = to_date(20130401,'YYYYMMDD');
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
SQL> DELETE FROM ORDERS
  2  WHERE CNUM = &CNUMBER AND PNUM = &PNUMBER AND ORDERDATE = to_date(&OD,'YYYYMMDD');
old   2: WHERE CNUM = &CNUMBER AND PNUM = &PNUMBER AND ORDERDATE = to_date(&OD,'YYYYMMDD')
new   2: WHERE CNUM = C111 AND PNUM = M001 AND ORDERDATE = to_date(20130404,'YYYYMMDD')
WHERE CNUM = C111 AND PNUM = M001 AND ORDERDATE = to_date(20130404,'YYYYMMDD')
                             *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "M001": invalid identifier
```

**Whats wrong??**

Comment: Add some quotes: AND PNUM = 'M001'

Answer (score 1):

CNUM = '&CNUMBER' AND PNUM = '&PNUMBER'

Not sure about &OD, do you need to quote that too?